# Rails 3.0.6 & 3.0.7 broke my destroy action...how do I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is directly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735253/why-does-destroy-action-trigger-http-authentication-in-production-in-rails-3)

I finally figured out that Rails 3.0.6 & 3.0.7 break my code. Given the code in that question, how do I fix it ?

Should I paste all that code over here?

Edit1: Issue resolved on linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to the latest jquery ujs driver which includes the CSRF token in each request to prevent your session from being reset since the [changes in 3.0.4](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails).